# Workbook.SaveAs crashes Excel with some workbooks but not others

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that makes some changes to a workbook and then saves that workbook in a different folder under a different filename.  The code for saving the workbook is:

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs sPass & "\" & sFile
```

Some workbooks save correctly, while others cause Excel to crash with the message

```
Microsoft Excel has stopped working
```

For the workbooks that crash when saved programmatically, if I exit the program before `SaveAs` and manually save them under the same filename that `SaveAs` was going to use, they save without a problem.

I've tried referring to the workbook by index, as:

```
Workbooks(workbookName).SaveAs sPass & "\" & sFile
```

Also tried just using a dummy filename:

```
Workbooks(workbookName).SaveAs "U:\someOtherDir\xyz.xlsm"
```

I've also tried surrounding `SaveAs` with `EnableEvents` disabling:

```
Application.EnableEvents=False
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs sPass & "\" & sFile
Application.EnableEvents=True
```

But the crash still occurs for some workbooks.  I haven't found a pattern as to which workbooks fail.  They open correctly, i.e. they aren't corrupted.

Comment: When you say "crash", what exactly happens? Any error messages or just a complete silent failure where Excel disappears as the process crashes?

Comment: I get a popup saying `Microsoft Excel has stopped working`, and then once I click through that popup, all instances of Excel close.

Comment: For the misbehaving workbooks, have you tried moving the data to a new workbook and then testing the macro?  Is there potential for some file corruption to have occured?

Comment: @AlanWaage, copying the data to a new workbook avoided the crash.  So it might be a file corruption issue.  But what's odd is that the "corrupt" file successfully opens, no message about needing to repair it.

Comment: Yeah, I have encountered the same. I never found out why it opened, or how the original got corrupted. Just chalked it up to a wierd MS bug.

Answer (score 0):

Also to do a proper `.SaveAs`, Use this. This specifies the correct `FileFormat`. This will ensure that the file is saved with the correct file format and will avoid the error message that you get when you manually open the file after that.

```
'
'~~~> Rest of the code
'
sFile = "U:\someOtherDir\xyz.xlsm"
Workbooks(workbookName).SaveAs sFile, 52
DoEvents
'
'~~~> Rest of the code
'
```

Comment: That didn't solve the problem; I still get the crash with a `Microsoft Excel has stopped working` message.